# How to check each item(string) of an array contain a particular letter?

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

The string array (2X3) looks like:

```
["abc" "acd"  "cdf"
 "any" "good" "bad"
]
```

To check if any item contains letter "a". The expected results are bool array:

```
[True  True  False
 True  False True
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `np.char` module which provides vectorised versions of many python string operations. For example:

```
np.char.find(string_array, 'a') != -1
# array([[ True,  True, False],
#        [ True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is exact what I am looking for.